# Creating a dictionary and adding a set as its value

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a set of a numbers that are related to a key. When the key is not in the dictionary I want to add it along with its value a set() and it the key exists I would like to just a number to the existing set for that key.  The way I did is like this:

```
for num in datasource:    
    if not key in dict.keys():
        dict[key] = set().add(num)
    else:
        dict[key].add(num)
```

But the issue with this is that when I add the number 03 it will add 0,3,03 to the set when what I really want to add is just 03.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to do from your description.

Comment: I'm not following what you're asking.  Can you provide some sample data that illustrates what you're looking at and what you're hoping to get?

Comment: You should not use `if not key in dict.keys()` for checking existence of a key, as it's complexity is `O(N)`in py2.x. Use `if not key in dict` to get `O(1)` lookup.

Comment: You should not use `dict` as a variable name, that's the dictionary constructor and you risk overwriting it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, for adding new set elements as values for a given key:

```
d = {}
d.setdefault(key, set()).add(value)
```

Alternatively, use a `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(set)
d[key].add(value)
```

Either solution will effectively create a [multimap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimap): a data structure that for a given key can hold multiple values - in this case, inside a `set`. For your example in particular, this is how you'd use it:

```
d = {}
for num in datasource:
    d.setdefault(key, set()).add(num)
```

Alternatively:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(set)
for num in datasource:
    d[key].add(num)
```

Comment: You need to use `d.setdefault(key, set()).add(value)`. `get` won't add the default value to the dictionary! Or, use a `defaultdict`.

Comment: @Blckknght yep, that's what I meant to write

Answer (score 2):

Use [dict.setdefault](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```
d.setdefault(key, set()).add(num)
```

Or use [collections.defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
d = collections.defaultdict(set)
...
d[key].add(num)
```

Answer (score 1):

An issue that I see is that `set().add(num)` returns `None`, so `dict[key]` will be initialized to `None`.

To fix this, you can initialize the set using `set([num])`:

```
if not key in dict.keys():
      dict[key] = set([num])
else:
      dict[key].add(num)
```